# .Net C# Reference a 3rd party JS library without using Nuget PM

Tags: nuget-package, github-third-party-apps

In my ASP.Net (C#) project, I'd like to a 3rd party JS library [heatmapper](https://github.com/dcmox/heatmapper) however this is library that can't be downloaded using `Nuget Package Manager` so to use it in my project I had to copy the code from this library and paste it in a newly created JS file in my project.

I was wondering if there is a more "efficient way" of using this library, instead of just copy pasting the code into my project I'd like to know if there is a way to reference this library so that if for example the library author introduced an update (like bug fixing) I wouldn't have to copy paste the code again.